# how to make mass assignment

Tags: java

How can i make mass asssignment for stack of variables?

I declare list of variables

```
String not_id, not_section, not_steet, not_sqTotal, not_sqLiving, not_sqKitchen, not_flat, not_floor, not_floors, not_text, user_phone1, user_phone2, user_contact, not_region, not_district, not_settle, not_price, not_photo, not_date, not_date_till, not_up, not_premium, not_status;
```

and i want alls of them to be equal to `""` - empty string(or `"a"`, does not matter just an example)

Comment: This  is  not a  language  feature of  Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
not_id = not_section = ... = not_status = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String not_id, not_section, not_steet, not_sqTotal, not_sqLiving, not_sqKitchen, not_flat, not_floor, not_floors, not_text, user_phone1, user_phone2, user_contact, not_region, not_district, not_settle, not_price, not_photo, not_date, not_date_till, not_up, not_premium, not_status;

not_id = not_section = not_steet = not_sqTotal = not_sqLiving = not_sqKitchen = not_flat = not_floor = not_floors = not_text = user_phone1 = user_phone2 = user_contact = not_region = not_district = not_settle = not_price = not_photo = not_date = not_date_till = not_up = not_premium = not_status = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String not_id=not_section=not_steet=not_sqTotal=not_sqLiving=not_sqKitchen=not_flat=not_floor=not_floors=not_text=user_phone1=user_phone2=user_contact=not_region=not_district=not_settle=not_price=not_photo=not_date=not_date_till=not_up=not_premium=not_status="a";
```

Comment: This assumes that every String but `not_id` is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

An array or other collection with a `for` loop.  Any solution you can come up with will reduce to that.  If the values are not homogeneous to belong in an array, you will have to have one assignment per variable that you want actually assigned to something.  There is no way around that.

In general if you want all objects initialized to something complex, you can create a wrapping class with a default constructor that encapsulates that, but that will be far more work in your case.  e.g.

```
Foo a = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
Foo b = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Can be replaced with

```
Foo a = new FooW();
```

Where `FooW` extends `Foo` with a default constructor that calls `super(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score -1):

Loop it

```
for (String s: list) {
            s=""; 
            //or 
            s="a";
        }
```

Comment: "I declare list of variables"....any ways congrats for the first downvote :) .I agree.. my assumption is wrong.